# PDO bulk import script

Tags: sql, pdo, import, bulkinsert

I am trying to create an import script, I have an example working after following [some outdated and unsafe tutorial] However this tutorial doesn't use PDO. Although this form is to only be used by a site supervisor I feel I should use PDO to help prevent SQL injection. Though I am not sure how I would change this for PDO statements?

Thanks

```
  (I already have my DB connection up here)

if ($_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0) {

//get the csv file 
$file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");


do {
    if ($data[0]) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users_tbl (username, staff_id, dept,  area) VALUES 
            ('" . addslashes($data[0]) . "',
             '" . addslashes($data[1]) . "', 
             '" . addslashes($data[2]) . "'         
            )
            ";
        $result = pg_query($sql);
                }
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "'"));
//redirect 
header('Location: import.php?success=1');
die;
}
```

Comment: Please, don't link to that terrible tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, there is not a little connection between PDO and CSV.

Every PHP user have to develop himself an ability **to separate matters**. There are **two** tasks for you:

1. to read a line from CSV file into **array**
2. to store an array data in database.

These 2 tasks are totally irrelevant to each other. After reading csv you may sore it anywhere. And CSV part won't be changed a bit. You may store in PDO data of any other source - and PDO code won't be changed a bit.

So, all you need to learn actually is **how to use PDO**. Well, Here you go https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

Another option would be using [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=LOAD%20DATA%20INFILE) query, which is way more suitable for the bulk imports